# Working with hit-test and UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, hittest

I'm writing my own map annotation layer which allows annotations to stick to a side of the screen (indicating something off screen). It works well. I can add/removre annotations. Rotate the map -> the annotations follow. Pinch to zoom -> the annotations stick to the side of the screen. They also clustuer and uncluster as you zoom in and out.

[image]

The problem is when I peform a pinch gesture (to zoom in, zoom, out, or rotate), both fingers must not be on a MYView (an annotation).

- MYViewController

  - MKMapView
  - MyAnnotationsView

    - NSArray of MYView (one for each annotation)

In order for the gestures to work at all but still allow for selecting of annotations, I have over-riddern hit test in MyAnnotationsView.

```
-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator){
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, point)){
            return subview;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then I am catching the touch event like so in MyView

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.delegate aggregateViewTouchesEnded:self];
}
```

Which tells MYAnntationsView that a touch occurred on an annotation. It can then tell the ViewController.

TLDR; When I pinch/rotate, both fingers must not be on an annotation.